# WordPress geolocation posts?

Tags: wordpress, location, geo

I would like to build something along the lines of this

http://demo.woothemes.com/cityguide/

Where I can click a point on the map which will link to a post, I would also like this to be search able by post code or town, so if you wanted to find shops in London, you'd type London and it would show all relative posts which are in that location.

All info is greatly appreciated guys :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options, I would look into the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html) using some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin makes what you want to achieve: [Post Google Map](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-google-map/) (from  WebDevStudios.com). You can add to any post a geolocation, then show all of them in the home page, with a link to each post from the map.